# Facebook Marketing API ads_management review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

We're trying to use the Facebook Marketing API ads_management permission. We want to use the permission to allow our clients to push the media that was created for them on our app to their personal ad manager

Based on their allowed usage, it sounds like we're utilising this correctly but every app review is being rejected with a fairly generic

**Your screencast doesn't show how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app. Unfortunately, we also weren't able to determine this from testing your app manually.**

For the first point - our screencast shows a brand/client navigating our app to where all their media lies - connect their facebook account - select the media and then push to the ad manager

This gives us the correct response as long as we use their sandbox environment on the Marketing API

On the second point **Unfortunately, we also weren't able to determine this from testing your app manually**

We provide test credentials for them to login into our application and go through the exact steps demonstrated in the screencast.

I know these reviews have been giving a number of developers issues but would love to hear if we're missing something really basic in our use because the usecase is really straightforward and not really sure how else to demonstrate it

Thanks